# Cannot make a div transparent

Tags: html, css

I am working [on this test page](http://triplov.com/secundario.html).

Scroll the page. The logo stays fixed on the background and this area I painted with purple scrolls over it. I made it purple just so I can see.

I am trying to make this area I painted with purple partially transparent, so I can see the background logo behind, as I scroll, like the purple area was a semi-transparent glass.  The color is (255,0,255,0.6) and is defined on the [`secundario.css`](http://triplov.com/_site2017/assets/css/secundario.css) styles as

```
body.index #main {
    padding-top: 5em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.6);   
}
```

Whatever I do, I cannot make this purple area semi-transparent. It stays opaque.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But on the linked page you have declared `background-color` twice, where the last has `transparent` as value, which overrides the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you found an alternative, but in case you are still wondering, I found your problem:

You have the *background image* as part of your `banner` section, which is a sibling to `main` (so, even if it looks like it, **they do NOT overlap**). If you want to see the image, you need to place it in one of the containers underneath, either `page-wrapper` or directly on the `body`.

Comment: ok, I will accept your answer because mine works but mine is a kind of hack. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```css
body.index #main {
    opacity: 0.5;
    padding-top: 5em;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The transparency works, you just can get different color results depends on element's color under the target with your `rgba`. Try to change `background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.6);` to `background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.1);` for example and you will see the difference.

Comment: @SpaceDog, I'm on your website now and that section has another look: https://snag.gy/iaYU39.jpg  (sorry for the second screen on screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

The transparency works, ok, but there is nothing below the purple area (just a blank page). You have set the logo background on your page header but that ends where your purple area starts.

The best would probably be to set the background on the `#page-wrapper` or similar parent element.

Comment: what do you mean there is nothing behind? isn't the main div scrolling over the other one?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. They are siblings and are laid out one after another.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your element to be transparent, it's really as easy as :

```
background-color: transparent;
```

But if you want it to be in colors, you can use:

```
background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.6);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: still opaque, no change.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered how to do it. I need to assign it to an independent `id`, not to a regular style.

Something is probably interfering with the current `#main` id, so, by creating a new one the problem is solved.

Thanks guys!